# How can I make a JS if statement to see if a value isn't certain strings?

Tags: javascript, html

Why does this JS not work? The goal is to enter something into the text box that isn't help, windows-xp, explicit, default, or nothing, press enter, and have that alert "Command doesn't exist".

```js
function checkInput() {
  var commandInput = document.getElementById("command-input")

  if (commandInput.value !== "help", "windows-xp", "explicit", "default", "") {
    alert("Command doesn't exist.");
  }

  event.preventDefault();

  document.getElementById("command-form").reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="command-form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Command" id="command-input">
  <input type="submit" onclick="checkInput();" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

Comment: you have to compare each string to commandInput.Value, you can't just say !== on the first one. You could also just put all these in string array and use an array function to iterate through them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
const validCommands = ["help", "windows-xp", "explicit", "default", ""];

if (!validCommands.includes(commandInput.value)) {
  alert("Command doesn't exist.");
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array (or Set) of the strings you want to permit, then check if the array `.includes` the value:

```js
function checkInput(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const commands = ["help", "windows-xp", "explicit", "default", ""];
  const { value } = document.getElementById("command-input");
  if (!commands.includes(value)) {
    console.log('Command doesnt exist ');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Carrying out command', value);
  commandForm.reset();
}
const commandForm = document.getElementById("command-form");
commandForm.addEventListener('submit', checkInput);
```

```html
<form id="command-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Command" id="command-input">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Also note that you should avoid inline handlers whenever possible, they [have too many gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), require global pollution, and are bad practice - attach event listeners properly using Javascript instead, like in the above snippet.